# AWS SQS valid characters

Tags: xml, unicode, amazon-sqs

Some messages I send via SQS come back with this error:

> Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSException: Invalid binary character '#x1' was found in the message body, the set of allowed characters is #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]

What do these codes actually mean? Obviously they are unicode codes, but any google search I've done comes up with formats slightly different to these ("#x"), and I'm struggling to understand them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are hexadecimal unicode ranges, just written a bit differently. #x9 is usually written as 0x9, #xE000 is 0xE0000

You can preview what the characters are e.g. here, using the traditional notation (0x9): http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm

Comment: thanks - traditional notation I understand. So I just replace the "#" with a "0" ?